# Creating heatmap from field/column in attribute table of shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I'm almost completely new to QGIS.

I have a layer from a shapefile loaded up into QGIS with a few thousand zones/features. There are also multiple fields/columns in the attribute table. I need to create a heatmap (or [something like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Population_density_countries_2018_world_map%2C_people_per_sq_km.svg/500px-Population_density_countries_2018_world_map%2C_people_per_sq_km.svg.png))

[image]

from one of those fields, let's call it X. Field X has a value for each zone/feature.

I already looked around a bit, but if I go to the layer properties --> Symbology, I don't see heatmap in the top dropdown menu.

Can anyone help me with how to create a heatmap?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GIS SE! Please make sure you take the [tour] to see what is expected of a high-quality, focused question.
In this case, you probably ought to provide more information about the data you're working with it. You're referencing "zones/features"; does this mean you have polygons? Heatmaps are generated from point features and output as a raster. What you've linked to is a choropleth map, though. Also, what version of Q are you using? The built-in heatmap was introduced at a certain version, so that matters.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I do have polygons (I think). I have a visible map when I imported the shapefile (from .shp  .dbf  and .shx). It looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/rrT5L9b.jpg

However, it's not linked to any realworld coordinates, but that's also not necessary.

And I'm using QGIS version 3.12.3

Answer (score 3):

If field *X* has the value you would like to use for your "heatmap", you can do the following:

1. Open the layer properties and go to the "Symbology" tab
2. Select ***Graduated*** in the pull-down menu at the top
3. Set the *Value* to *X*
4. Choose the desired number of classes in *Classes* and press the *Classify* button.

   [image]
5. Click on the *Apply* or *OK* button to see the result.