# QGIS Heatmap not available?

Tags: qgis, layers, heat-map, vector-layer

I'm using QGIS Version 3.16.4. I thought one can do heatmaps by going to the properties of a layer and selecting it under symbolization. But as you can see, it's not available in the dropdown menu. Does anyone know what's the reason for that or how I can activate the heatmap option? The Vector-Layer only consists of polygons which have 3 attributes, so nothing fancy there. Maybe there's a plugin I can use? The two which I found need a timestamp unfortunately, which is not part of my layer
[image: Layer properties -> symbolization]

I know you can do something similar by using *graduated* in the drop down menu, it's explained in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363389/creating-heatmap-from-field-column-in-attribute-table-of-shapefile-in-qgis) but I still want to know why I can't do it with heatmaps.

Comment: Heatmaps are available for point layers only. Covert yout polygons to points, e.g. using `Menu Processing  / Toolbox / Geometry by expression` with this expression: `centroid ($geometry)`

Comment: oh, did not know that, thanks. Well that's a bit disappointing, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be available for polygons...Guess I'll use graduated then or convert to points

Comment: The very concept of a heatmap is based on points as it is a kind of representing density, each point having a radius (kind of a buffer) so that it overlaps the symbols of other features. You could emulate that using buffers and layer/feature blending modes with polygons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heatmap renderer is only available on point vector layers.

But you probably don't want a heatmap, you probably want a graduated symbology (which I think is your Abgestuft option), which you can use to make the polygons more red based on an attribute.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I knew about the graduated symbology, just didn't know heatmaps are for point layers only :)